# Split string into dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a `char` array given to me by a user or an application `"Hello,My,Name,Is,Test"`.

What I need to be able to do is split this on the comma store this in an dynamic array as I will never know the number of commas or the size of the string.

I need to store this so each item can be requested individually by another method like

```
GetItem(int index)
{   
   ... 
   return Array[index];
   ...
}
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this. You can do multiple iterations that 1. determine the number of elements in the string, (2. determine the length of the elements), 3. fills the final array. 2. can be replaced with using a buffer that you can guarantee to not overflow. Or using a stack/list to add new items and convert it to an array afterwards. Sure there are even more ways to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - tokenise array of chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022468/c-tokenise-array-of-chars)

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't know* and have not even an upper limit to the numbers of commas in the string, you have to parse the string and dynamically reallocate the array. There are several strategies, and the one below isn't really optimal, being conducive to memory fragmentation, but it's simple to describe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str       = "This,is,a,comma,delimited,string,with,a,length,of,whatever";
    char **array    = NULL;
    char *p;
    size_t  items = 0, q;
    char *sepa      = ",";

    p = str;
    for (;;)
    {
            p += strspn(p, sepa);
            if (!(q = strcspn(p, sepa)))
                    break;
            if (q)
            {
                    array           = realloc(array, (items+1) * sizeof(char *));
                    array[items]    = malloc(q+1);
                    strncpy(array[items], p, q);
                    array[items][q] = 0;
                    items++;
                    p += q;
            }
    }
    for (q = 0; q < items; q++)
    {
            printf("(%s) ", array[q]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* Here we have a problem. How do we return to the caller the information
       about how many items do we have? A common solution is to return the number
       of items PLUS ONE, and that one is NULL */

    array           = realloc(array, (items+1) * sizeof(char *));
    array[items]    = NULL;

    /* So this code can work without needing to know the value of "items" */
    for (q = 0; array[q]; q++)
            printf("(%s) ", array[q]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

BTW, I have omitted to check whether `realloc` (or `malloc`) returns NULL, signifying a memory error.

An alternative allocation strategy is to use `realloc` in chunks, i.e., you keep two counters, `items` and `really_allocated_items`, and only realloc when the two are equal. When you do, you increment `really_allocated_items` by, say, 64, and realloc that number of items. This way, you only run one allocation every 64, and waste at most 63 pointers.

Other strategies exist, using an incrementing chunk size instead of the fixed 64, but they are only implemented when memory and performance constraints are really tight.

**NOTE** this implementation *intentionally* does not use `strtok`, because `strtok` *modifies the original string* and in some cases this might not be allowed (might even gain you a coredump).

Comment: The question did use an array `char str[] = "...";` which is modifiable.  You're correct that your code using `char *str = "...";` would run foul of modifying a string literal if it attempted to do so.  You're also correct that `strtok()` is a nasty piece of work, in general.  Sometimes, it is adequate, but I pretty much always go out of my way to avoid it.  Incrementing the array size by 1 can lead to quadratic behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple implementation using `strtok()` of maximum word length of less than `10`

You can do it in other way also, for this don't forget to `#include<string.h>`

```
char str[] = "Hello,My,Name,Is,Test";
char delims[] = ",";
char *result =NULL;
char final[10][10];
int i=0;
result = strtok( str, delims );
strcpy(final[i],result);
i++;
while( result != NULL ) {
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );
    strcpy(final[i],result);
    i++;
}
```

---

Footnote : Here first call to `strtok()` uses `str` as the first parameter but all subsequent calls has `NULL`

Comment: I hope , this may help you a little

Comment: Hello All, 

Thank you all for the time and effort you have spent helping me out. I will try your suggestions and let you know which one worked for me

Comment: That's an ugly repetition in the code.  Why not: `char *data = str; while ((result = strtok(data, delims)) != NULL) { strcpy(final[i++], result); data = NULL; }` which also eliminates the copying of NULL when the `strtok()` returns NULL (the behaviour of `strcpy()` with a null pointer for the source is undefined!).